# Difference between SharePoint Content Type and List Definition

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm watching some SharePoint 2010 training DVD's and the instructor has just introduced Content Types and List Definitions. I'm a bit lost. They both seem like List Templates to me. MSDN's explanations aren't terribly helpful. Can anyone explain the difference, or give me some examples where you would use each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content types are a way of structuring your data. Documents for example can be organized by having a content type 'meeting report' or 'sales presentation'. Each content type defines the specific set of metadata that applies to that document type and potentially contains a template. That template can be an empty meeting report (Word document) for example.

A list definition is a blueprint for a list or library. Examples are a document library, a picture library, a discussion board, ... The list definition defines which content types (potentially multiple) are attached to the list/library upon creation (users can modify this later) and determines which list views are created by default.

Once you have customized a list/library, you can generate a list template from it for later re-use. You can think of this as a user-created list definition. (It's not really a definition, but the concept is pretty much the same.)

Comment: Thank you Tom, that helps a lot!